# What does pow in blockchain solves?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

In a distributed system 2/3rd of the system has to be honest to maintain a finite state of data (fault tolerance). Even after introducing pow, blockchain can tolerate only 1/3rd of dishonest nodes which is same as a algorithm without pow. So what does pow actually solves?

Comment: "Proof of work" confirms that a node really did "mining". Else you could send millions of wrong results to the network without mining and "win" due to a > 51% share. With "POW", everyone can see those results are wrong very easy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really a programming question. Try bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Comment: @dognose Are you saying, a single server can win 51% of the share?

Comment: @minisha: Sure, why not. Especially since the miners these days mostly operate as "pools". A single pool can get a very significant share of mining power.

Comment: @Thilo okay. Can you help to move the question to bitcoin then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POW means that you cannot just spin up a million lightweight nodes to get a higher quorum for yourself. You have to come up with a proportionate amount of computing power. That is an important property in an open-membership network.

There are other mechanisms to distribute voting rights among participants, but most of them rely on some sort of mutually trusted authority. For block-chains, a possible, equally decentralized, alternative is proof-of-stake. But that comes with its own set of trade-offs.

Comment: So pow doesn't solve Byzantine General Problem rite?

Comment: In the Byzantine General Problem you know a priori who your N generals are. You don't have to deal with a potentially infinite, constantly fluctuating, anonymous set of participants.

Comment: I been keep on hearing from people that bitcoin blockchain is the one that first solves byzantine general problem. So I am totally confused

Comment: As per my understanding, It didn't solve byzantine general problem. However, bitcoin blockchain is the first application to port distributed system in a decentralised setting with the limitation of distributed systems

Comment: Did my understanding make sense?

Comment: @Minisha Did you get your query answered??

Comment: @Minisha Look at this https://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09997.html

Comment: @Minisha Even though I myself is trying to grasp all this, it may help you in your search.

Comment: @Minisha Also Read this https://web.archive.org/web/20140603221234/http://expectedpayoff.com/blog/2013/03/22/bitcoin-and-the-byzantine-generals-problem/